# Prove $1/\delta\phi(x/\delta)$ is approximation to the identity

Tags: real-analysis

I am given the definition of approximation to the identity:

A family $\{K_\delta\}$ s.t

1. $\int K_\delta=1$
2. $|K_\delta|\leq C_1/\delta$ for some $C_1$
3. $|K_\delta(x)|\leq C_2\delta |x|^{-2}$

Now for $\phi(x)$, it is measurable, non-negative, supported on (-1,1), and $\int \phi(x) dx=1$. Show that $1/\delta\phi(x/\delta)$ is approximation to the identity.

The first condition is easy to show. The second reduced to $\phi(x)$ is bounded, how's that? I am considering $\phi=limit_n \phi_n$

$\phi_n(x)=n, x=0$

$\phi_n(x)=1/2, x\in(-1,1)$ and 0 o/w. It is measurable, nonnegative, supported on (-1,1) and has integral 1. But the second condition is not satisfied. Where did I go wrong? Any hint or clarification of definition is appreciated.

Comment: Generally such $\phi$ are also assumed to be at least continuous.

Comment: I also wonder whether it should be one condition. Maybe I should ask the professor.